Bigquery Parameters with connected Google sheet - If parameter is null then return all
I have a Google sheet connected to Bigquery. The query has a parameter that references cell B1. If cell B1 is empty I want to return all results. I've tried using IFNULL but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I have so far...
SELECT
Product_Code, 
Product_Description,
Location_Code

FROM `t1`

WHERE
Location_Code IN UNNEST(SPLIT(IFNULL(@CODE,'%'),","))

The query states "Update the cell referenced by parameter 'CODE' to be text or a number"
I was thinking I might be able to put a '%' or '*' in the cell as a work around but it doesn't seem to work.
Any help is appreciated.
